# Programmatically trigger button click event on AG grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have a action button in each row of my ag grid. I am using CellRenderer to show the button. Individual button clicks are working fine. But I want to programmatically trigger the click event for all button on click of another button. To batch process multiple rows. Is that possible?

Main Grid

```
const GridDemo = () => {

  const gridRef = useRef();
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(); 

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'make',
      filter: true,
      cellRenderer: ButtonRenderer
    },
    { field: 'model', filter: true },
    { field: 'price' }
  ];

  // DefaultColDef sets props common to all Columns
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => ({
    sortable: true
  }), []);


  // Example load data from server
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json')
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(rowData => setRowData(rowData))
  }, []);

const handleClick =() => { }


  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click All</button>

      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}>

        <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API

          rowData={rowData} // Row Data for Rows

          columnDefs={columnDefs} // Column Defs for Columns
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef} // Default Column Properties

        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Button Renderer

```
const ButtonRenderer = (props) => {

    const clickHandler = () => {
        console.log('Clicked!!!')
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
    )
}

export default ButtonRenderer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the api method `getCellRendererInstances` to get the cell renderer instances for the desired column, on which you can call your `clickHandler` function. Please note:

> Note that this method will only return instances of the cell renderer
> that exists. Due to row and column virtualisation, renderers will only
> exist for cells that the user can actually see due to horizontal and
> vertical scrolling.

Update your `handleClick` function to the following:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const instances = gridRef.current.api.getCellRendererInstances();
    instances.forEach((x) => {
      x.clickHandler();
    });
    console.log(gridRef);
  };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-uhcnrb?file=index.js).

[Documentation on getCellRendererInstances](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/)